# How to add mintues to date using php?

Tags: php

I want to add 30 minutes to the current date. But if i do so, it displays 1970-01-01 01:03:33(Unix timestamp).How to retrieve the result in a format that strtotime() parser understands?

Here is my code:

```
$date1      =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$newdate    =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+30 minutes', $date1));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the answer

```
echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime("+30 minutes"));
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because `date()` returns a string, and you are adding 30 minutes to a string instead of a date.
Try this:

```php
$newdate    =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+30 minutes', now()));
```

or

```php
$date1      =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$newdate    =   date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+30 minutes', strtotime($date1)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` expects a timestamp as its second parameter, not a formatted date. But in any case, you can just work with timestamps:

```
$newdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+30*60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$curDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 minutes", strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$now      =   time();
$later    =   $now + 60*30;
```